# html/css Really confused on where the top part white space come from

Tags: html, css

```css
.about {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

.about img {
  width: 60%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <section id="top">
    <div class="top">
      <h1>text</h1>
      <h1>text</h1>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

So I just run this by itself, and I get this random
[white space at the top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNAUo.jpg)

```css
.about {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <section id="top">
    <div class="top">
      <h1>text</h1>
      <h1>text</h1>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

I then delete the whole ".about img" section and the [white space disappears (which I would want)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vzTQ.jpg)

It doesn't matter if I delete all the content inside .about img, the white space stays there. The white space only goes away if I delete the whole .about img.

Even if I delete h1, .about, or the word "img", or literally everything else, the white space stays there.

As you can see, my html did not use the about class (I did but I commented/deleted them)

I would really love an explanation as to why deleting the ".about img"section get rid of the white spaces when my html doesn't even use .about or img, and as to why deleting other stuff doesn't change anything.

Note: I have tried the universal selector, which was able to make the white space disappear, but I am just really curious why ".about img" affects the spaces. Sorry if this is obvious or.

Note 2: I also have tried adding margin: 0 to top and main, but none of them removed the white spaces.

Thanks!

Comment: I can't see any difference when that section of code is removed.

Comment: At first try body { padding:0; margin:0;} if not work then you using h1 tag so for h1 tag line height value is much if we don't set explicitly. SO try then h1 { line-height: 24px} or less.

Comment: Then perhaps is this something to do with my machine/environment? As you can see from my links, there is a difference when I run it. I have tried removing all heads and the same problem still exists.

Comment: @Quentin You are right, when it runs on stack overflow there is really no difference. Would you know what else might be causing my machine to display it incorrectly?

Comment: @Hanif I tried both, together, and separately, it didn't remove the white spaces. Thank you